# unable to redirect to home.php post login getting a warning

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to connect to database and get results. My login system is working. I am getting results (checked with `echo` command). I'm not using `MD5()`,`SHA256()` because I am testing. Later I will implement them. The problem is `header()` function is giving a warning and it does not redirects to home page.

I am calling login.php (with html layout) in index.php file, login.php calls PDO's (user) `login()` function and returns back `true`/`false`; if result is true i am redirecting to home.php

**warning:**

> Warning
>   : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thesho28/public_html/greetme/index.php:51) in /home/thesho28/public_html/greetme/includes/login.php on line 38

I don't understand because I am not using `header()` function on index.php besides same code is working on wamp (localhost)

....... Login.php code is below ...........

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/greetme/core/database/connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['login']))
{
  $cemail=$_POST['email'];
  $pwd=$_POST['password'];
  $email=$getFromU->checkInput($cemail);
  $password=$getFromU->checkInput($pwd);
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
       $loginerr="Invalid Email";
    }                             
     else
    {
       // checked, i get back the result from session variables
      if($getFromU->login($email,$password)===false) 
        { 
          $loginerr="Incorrect Email/Password";
          $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        }
         else
         {
            $username=$_SESSION['username'];
            $last_login=$_SESSION['last_login'];
             echo $last_login; echo $username; 
            // getting results back, login is successful
            /* $result=$getFromU->updateUserLastLogin($username,$last_login); 
               if($result===false)
               { 
                 echo "error";
                }
                else
                {
                 $_SESSION['new_login']=date('D, d F, Y');
               }
        */
           header('Location:../home.php');
         }
    }
}        

?>
<div class="d-flex flex-col" id="login-section">
  <div class="card-body bg-primary">
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope input-group-addon"></i><label for="email"></label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="" required placeholder="Email"
          <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
            {
              $email=$_SESSION['email'];
              echo 'value="'.$email.'"';
            }
          ?>  
          > 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <i class="fa fa-lock input-group-addon"></i><label for="password"></label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="" placeholder="Password" required>  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-light" value="LOG IN" name="login">
      </div>    
      <?php 
      if(isset($loginerr))
      {
        echo '<span class="error">'.$loginerr.'</span>';
      }
    ?>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

---------------- code of pdo is below -------------

```
<?php
class User {
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct($pdo){
        $this->pdo=$pdo;
    }

    public function checkInput($var){
        $var=htmlspecialchars($var);
        $var=trim($var);
        $var=stripslashes($var);
        return $var;
    }


    public function login($email, $password){
        //$e=$email;
        //$pwd=$password;
        $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare("SELECT userid, username, display_name, last_login FROM user WHERE email=:email and password=:password");
        $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count=$stmt->rowCount();
        echo $email."<br>"; echo $password."<br>"; echo$count;
        if($count > 0)
        {   
            $_SESSION['username']=$user->username;
            $lastlogin=$user->last_login;

            if(strlen($lastlogin)<=0)
            {
                // if last_login is null then store current date and time as session
                $_SESSION['last_login']=date('l, d F, Y : H:i:s');
                $last_login=$_SESSION['last_login'];
            }
            else{ $_SESSION['last_login']=$last_login; }
            $username=$_SESSION['username'];
            $_SESSION['displayname']=$user->display_name;
            //header('Location:home.php');

        }
        else
        {   //echo 'error'; 
         return false; 

        }
    }

  }

?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. At first I was getting fatal error on web hosting while on localhost it worked. After 3-4 support tickets I got it working myself. I tried a lot but it baffles me. Everything works fine on localhost. Please Check the screenshots ... It works on localhost ...

1. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=3164433
2. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=3163240

Thank you.

Comment: I want to tell you guys i forgot to remove comment from header() function. I commented to see if I can make it work by using header() function in pdo. Both options do not work. I have seen it does not work :(

Comment: You should not also be using md5 or sha256 for passwords.. you should be using PHP's password hashing API.. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: try to replace the header('Location: home.php'); with this echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.php">'; same result.

Comment: @bdalina I really think that's a bad practice. The `<meta>` should be placed in the `<header>` tag, and just `echo`'ing in the PHP script should not be the right place to do it.

Comment: remove `echo $email."<br>"; echo $password."<br>"; echo$count;` line from `login` function

Comment: @Raymond: thank you so much for the tip. Actually I was looking for tips on securing connection strings and passwords. #Mehul: Yes, I have removed the echo statement from login function. I did that to see if the values are being passed to the function or not. I did not remove the statement in my post to let others know that i am getting the values still it does not work. I am sorry but nothing works. I am stuck at this point at webhost while at localhost i am creating a feature of adding post,commenting post, liking post, and sharing post.

Comment: @badlina - I replaced header() function in login.php with echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=home.php" />'; statement. It now redirects to me to home.php. However, I still see the same warning for 1sec before i am redirected to home.php.

Comment: Finally I solved it ........ Now i do not get any error. However, I see empty login form for 1second before i am taken to home.php. This is because of using echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=home.php" />'; statement. If I user header() function the old error reoccurs